# Paste text into a Word Document with a specific format

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

I'm working on a macro but I'm stuck at this point. I'm copying text from one word document to another, but I need this text to be pasted in a specific format, neither the source formatting, or it's destination's.

Is it possible to determine that the text I'll be pasting, gets pasted with a specific font, a specific size, and a specific color?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be as follows:

1. Start recording a new macro.
2. Paste your text.
3. Select the pasted text.
4. Set the formatting (font, size, color) as you require.
5. Stop recording the macro.
6. Borrow heavily from the auto-generated selection and formatting code of the new macro for use in your original macro.